# Git post-receive to checkout only those files that have been modified/added in the push?

Tags: git

I have been using post-receive scripts in my git repositories with the following commands to checkout all of the files in the repository:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
```

I am wanting to do something similar but only checkout the files that have been modified or added in the push. Once the files have been checked out the post-receive script will then run some other commands on these files and remove the files at the end so that the directory will be empty.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `git diff` to give you a list of files

```
git diff --name-only from..to
```

in a [post-receive](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) hook that'll be I think

```
git diff --name-only $1..$2
```

as this hook receives `oldrev`, `newrev` and `ref` on standard input

Comment: I don't need a list of files I need to checkout the new files to a directory. I probably should mention that I am doing this using a bare repository hosted on a server.

Comment: Once you know which files are relevant [it's then possible to dump them wherever you want](https://github.com/AD7six/git-hooks/blob/develop/utils.php#L101). But you need to know which files to action first, and you aren't going to do a checkout at all.

Comment: OK so can I pass the git diff output to your copyFiles php function form inside the post-receive hook script?